# search that matches [groovy] or [grails] but not [gradle]

Tags: support, search, tag-search

I tried entering `[groovy] or [grails] -[gradle]` in the search box, but I still get gradle-tagged posts in the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a characteristic of the "or" operator to be parsed last. The results you are seeing is any question tagged groovy, *or* any question that is tagged grails but not gradle: `(groovy) || (grails && !gradle)`.

If you want questions without gradle but with either groovy or grails, you must use double negation along with the or operator so it applies on both sides: [`[groovy] -[gradle] or [grails] -[gradle]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grails+-gradle+or+groovy+-gradle) (do not use the search box to type this and instead write it directly in the url, since the search box changes the ordering and skews the results).

I've pointed out [this before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239158/213575), through I don't know if it's the desired behavior or not.

Comment: Isn't this the same as -[gradle] [grails] or [groovy]?

Comment: @Ben nope, that would return [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28134369/792066) question which is tagged with [groovy]. The search isn't proceeded starting from left or right, but based on operators, starting by "not", then "and" lastly 'or".

Comment: If you use the search box that question is returned as it gets rewritten to what the OP has, but I can't find that question if I change the URL as you suggest... The operator order of precedence you suggest makes sense in that respect.